# Compute constant in header file at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a header file that contains functions based upon the user OS, it does so using:

```
#ifdef _WIN32 // Windows
...
#else // Linux/Unix code (I know it will be either Windows or Linux/Unix)
...
#endif
```

The functions defined in their appropriate blocks are currently called from `main` at runtime and store a constant, but this got me thinking: *Can I compute this constant in the header at compile?*

Something like:

```
#ifdef _WIN32 
// function here; call it foobar()
#define WINCONST foobar()
#else
// function here; call it xfoobar()
#define NIXCONST xfoobar()
#endif
```

However I am not sure that you can use function calls in the `#define` preprocessor directive. I know that you can use it in a manner such as `#define ADD(x, y) (x + y)` but thats about it.

Comment: _"However I am not sure that you can use function calls in the #define preprocessor directive"_ You can use anything at preprocessor directives that will be expanded to the appropriate text for you.

Comment: @pstatix maybe irrelevant but why would you do this? What not just precalculate wincost separate and just put the value here? Or is winconst itself not a constant and depends on more compiler variables not shown above?

Comment: @SiddharthChabra Both `WINCONST` and `NIXCONST` perform a calculation on a series of loops to determine the amount of user time a function spends on the users system. They are not going to be the same value for every user because some users may have a more advanced machine; so they should be computed at either run time or compile time.

Comment: @SiddharthChabra How do you "precalculate" something to store the constant when compiling?

Comment: @pstatix if it depends on user machines are you planning to complie the solution on each users machine separately? The minute you use a function like std::clock your expression is no longer constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
constexpr uint32_t foo()
{
    // complex calculations...
    return 0;
}

uint32_t const SomeConstant = foo();
```

Side note: `foo` will be evaluated to a compile time constant, as long as no non-compile-time arguments are passed to, so above definition then will result in a compile time constant as well (equivalent to `uint32_t SomeConstant = 7;`). However, code won't break if you remove constexpr qualification from `foo` unless you use the constant where compile time constants are required (e. g. array definitions). This may be desired or not, in latter case, `constexpr` provides stronger guarantees (i. e. compilation failure whenever `foo(/*...*/)` is not compile-time-constant):

```
uint32_t constexpr SomeConstant = foo();
```

Comment: Not sure, but won't `someConstant` not being a `constexpr` mean that `foo()` does not have to be called during compilation time and thus it's `constexpr`ness will be useless in this example?

Comment: `constexpr` functions are evaluated at compile time whenever this is possible. So if parameters (so there are at all) are compile time constants, the result will be as well, ending in something equivalent to `uint32_t SC = 7;`, which is a compile time constant as well... (Side note: Matter changes if `foo` is not constexpr or called with non-compile-time-constant arguments.)

Comment: I think it would be best to replace const by constexpr, so that in the future, if foo becomes not constexpr anymore, we have a compilation error.

Comment: @aconcagua should it not be return some_const_val? If you return 0 it might as well be uint32_t const SomeConstant = 0?

Comment: _"`constexpr` functions are evaluated at compile time whenever this is possible"_ is only a QoI issue, however, const integrals act like constexpr so it's fine but misleading here.

Comment: Apparently in C++11 I cannot have anything more than a single `return` in the body of a `constexpr`.

Comment: I need to call [`std::clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock) from inside but it says it is non-constexpr therefore I cannot.

Comment: Selected as answer for how to do this; unfortunately not able to apply to case where I need it due to `std::clock` not be a `constexpr`. Stuck with the run time solution.

Comment: @pstatix With `std::clock`, there is another issue unrelated to constexpr: You get current time from, so at run-time, you get a timestamp when the programme was *started*. If it *was* constexpr, you'd get a timestamp when the programme was *compiled*, so it would be the same on *every* programme run! (If you really want to achieve the latter, you might get the time externally and pass it to compiler via -D flag (if GCC/clang), e. g. in Makefile, or depending on IDE, have some script being called as pre-build step.)